# My method to run a bash script automatically when any Desktop Manager is landed,does not work as expected

Tags: command-line, bash, mount, sudo, root

I would like to run a shell script automatically when my ubuntu 18.04 installation has landed and I see the desktop manager fully loaded. The script should be executed regarless of the desktop manager that I'm using. I've found this tutorial and I have followed it :

https://xtrace.blogspot.com/2020/02/run-script-at-startup-of-ubuntu.html

the script that I want to run automatically is the following one :

```
#!/bin/bash

/home/zi/Desktop/Work/./I9-20.sh

/home/zi/Desktop/Work/I9/arm32/./boot-bullseye2.sh
```

and I have placed it on the folder /home/zi/Desktop/Work

this is the content of the file I9-20.sh :

```
sudo mount -t nfs -o nolock,local_lock=all 192.168.1.6:/home/ziomario/Scrivania/Dati/Data/Nano/I9 /home/zi/Desktop/Work/I9
```

this is the content of the file boot-bullseye2.sh :

```
qemu-system-aarch64 -M virt -m 2048 -smp 2 -cpu host,aarch64=off -enable-kvm \
-kernel /home/zi/Desktop/Work/I9/arm32/debian11-bullseye/vmlinuz-5.10.0-5-armmp-lpae \
-initrd /home/zi/Desktop/Work/I9/arm32/debian11-bullseye/initrd.img-5.10.0-5-armmp-lpae \
-append 'root=/dev/vda2' \
-device usb-ehci -device usb-kbd -device usb-mouse -usb -serial stdio \
-device virtio-gpu-pci,virgl=on,xres=1920,yres=1080 -display sdl,gl=on \
-drive if=none,file=/home/zi/Desktop/Work/I9/arm32/hda-bullseye2.qcow2,format=qcow2,id=hd \
-device virtio-blk-device,drive=hd -netdev user,id=mynet \
-device virtio-net-device,netdev=mynet \
-bios edk2-arm-code.fd \
-no-reboot
```

(individually,these scripts work well). This is the file raspy.desktop that I have placed inside the folder /usr/share/applications :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=raspboot
Comment=raspberry vm start
Exec=/home/zi/Desktop/Work/rasp
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Icon=vlc
```

In addition I have added this line inside the /etc/fstab file :

```
192.168.1.6:/home/ziomario/Scrivania/Dati/Data/Nano/I9 /home/zi/Desktop/Work/I9 nfs rw,relatime,noauto,user 0 0
```

and I have added to the /etc/sudoers file these lines :

```
zi ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/mount
zi ALL = NOPASSWD: /home/zi/Desktop/Work/rasp
```

I have also added the "raspboot" service on the startup application tab of  "gnome tweaks".

It works only when I open a terminal and I write the command "sudo mount" by hand (it means that it does not ask for the passwd when I'm not root). but it's not enough for me. The script should be activated when cinnamon is ready to go. At this point I think that the problem is inside this file :

```
/usr/share/applications/raspy.desktop

[Desktop Entry]

Name=raspboot

Comment=raspberry vm start

Exec=/home/zi/Desktop/Work/rasp

Terminal=true

Type=Application

Icon=vlc
```

**OR** gnome tweaks does not work well. (I have even put Terminal= false ; but it didn't work).

What do u think is wrong ?

Comment: Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading  the RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages you got on your system. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis.

Comment: I photographed the situation regarding how I configured everything. I can't give you the commands that I've issued when I've wrote them on the terminal, because I tried various combinations of settings. But you can do a nice thing : you can configure the files exactly as I did and check what happens.

Comment: Why would I buy hardware to duplicate your system, install the same software AND configure like it seems you did? And for free?

Comment: I mean,not exactly as I did. For example you don't need to have my exact hardware. Man,are u joking with me ? It is enough to have ubuntu 18.04. I really want to give you more informations,but I don't know how can I do that better than I've already did. Explain to me how can I help you more. Are u aware that there are a lot of posts here on askubuntu written worst than mine,where have been given less informations than what I did but those guys have been helped really well ?

Comment: you can also suggest a different method. don't be so demanding.

Comment: There are two common ways to autostart, using `systemd` (at the system or at the user level) or using `.desktop` launchers (for all users or for an individual user) in `autostart` folders. Did you try either of these approaches?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1npiQC6NGmk4xZZk3kcIywu2nKec_2qw1/view